# Accessing json array by string? (Converting string to var. name)

Tags: php, string, json, variables

I'm trying to post the "lang_id" var. to "get_lang.php" with jquery to get (json) data.
But I can't access the data.

Now trying to do

```
  var r = $(this).attr('rel');
  var v = data.r;
```

But this doesn't work because of "r" is string IMO.

Also tried

```
data.window[r] // but...
```

---

**"get_lang.php";**

```
$lang_id = (int) ($_POST['lang_id']);

if($lang_id == 1)
{
     $lang['simple'] = 'aaa';
     $lang['array'] = 'bbb';
}

if($lang_id == 2)
{
     $lang['simple'] = 'ccc';
     $lang['array'] = 'ddd';
}

print json_encode($lang);
```

**my.js;**

```
$.post("get_lang.php", { "lang_id": 2}, function(data){

   $('.lang').each(function() {

     var r = $(this).attr('rel');
     var v = data.r;

     $(this).text(v);

    });

},"json");
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var v = data[r];
```

The dot notation interprets r as a string and not as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to tell jQuery the right content type.  Put this at the TOP of your `get_lang.php` file

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

And see if jQuery likes it.